# How to convey importance - most important to least important?

Tags: navigation, lists, hierarchy

I have some 20 steps for planning an event. Say birthday planning. Some steps are very important(booking a hall), and some are least(fireworks). Important steps obviously should be executed as early as possible. I want to navigate user from most to least important steps. So how should I convey that this is important than this, and gain the attention on most important step at first?

Comment: Sujit, have you a design in mind for the UI as yet? It would be easier to help refine an existing design.

Comment: Couple of ideas: dividing between required and optional, adding icons to top-priority, sorting by "importance"

Comment: Hey Erics, I am thinking about a timeline like sequence of such steps, wherein non-imp steps will be at down the page and gray colored, while at the top of the page, imp things will be there with some fresh color, more white-spaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lots of possible solutions : ordered list, bigger items, icons, colors, etc.

In your case, you'll have groups of things to do so I guess it's better to regroup them. You could have something like this (this is just a quick mockup) :

[image: todo list]

It's better to avoid long list since they are harder to manage and read.